# Can I disable the token expiration within the simple:rest-accounts-password package in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, authentication, package, token

Is there a way to disable the token expiration within the `simple:rest-accounts-password` package in Meteor? I found out that before Meteor 1.4 there was no expiration attached to it. Downgrading could be a solution but I would like to know if there are any alternatives for this issue, since I think I'm not the only one running into this problem.

I'm using this package for Meteor: https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest-accounts-password

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you found regarding the pre-1.4 expiration? AFAICT, Meteor and this package used expiration in its current form for at least 3 years. I don't think that you can completely disable expiration without implementing your own mechanism, but you can set a longer duration.

Comment: How do I set a longer duration? As far as I know you can't edit that.

Comment: Send the `loginExpirationInDays` to `Account.config`.

Comment: So where do I find this? I'm new to Meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `server` directory, inside a file called `main.js`, add below code;

```
Accounts.config({
  loginExpirationInDays: 1 // any duration that you desire
});
```

Disabling, as far as I know, is not possible, you can delay the expiry though.

Comment: Set `loginExpirationInDays` to `null` to disable login expiry.